# Empty pdf generated when converting docx to pdf using xdocreport

Tags: apache, apache-poi, xdocreport

An empty pdf file is getting generated when I am making use of below code to convert a docx file to pdf. Can anyone please help me to rectify the issue.

[Docx File](http://www.filedropper.com/mtgmin) 
[PDF File](http://www.filedropper.com/mtgmin_1)

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.OutputStream;
  import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
  import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
  import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
  public class ConversionDocxToPDF {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {


        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\MtgMin.docx"));
       XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);        

        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create(); 

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\MtgMin.pdf"));
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: You might want to try the newest release of `xdocreport` to see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: I am making use of fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-1.0.0. Is there any latest release for that?

Comment: Did you look? https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport